# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable while giving title to the matplotlib.pyplot of line line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, typeerror

Actually I want to give title to my line plot of matplotlib.pyplot line plot,
but I am facing this error

"TypeError: 'str' object is not callable while giving title to the matplotlib.pyplot of line line plot"

Here is my code.

`
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pydataset import data

austres = data('austres')
austres.head()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,4)) # plot_size
plt.plot(austres['time'], austres['austres'], 'v-g')
plt.title(label="Population Graph")`enter code here`
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Population')
`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgtea.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probable reason is you assigned to `plt.title` before. Someting like

```
plt.title = "Population Graph"
```

But what it does is to change the `plt.title` function of matplotlib to now refer to a string! Language is flexible so you can do this and results in error after you try call it. It tries like `"Population Graph"()`.

To solve it:

- either detect that `plt.title = ...` code and erase it and re-run the script
- if this is a jupyter like enivornment (e.g. notebook), detect that line and delete it if not already and then restart the kernel and re run again.

Comment: when I re-run the script , this worked perfect, Thanks